# How to center text on specific character position?

Tags: c#, winforms, text

I have a string with text and I want to output it centering on specific character position.

Is there a way to do so using, for example, label?

Or should I better consider drawing a string using GDI+ measuring each character length and then manually drawing it where I need, centered?

Example, to be clearer:

String: "Lorem Ipsum", Position: 2.

From this, I need the string displayed in such way that character "r" will be in the middle of whatever display box (label, etc.).

Comment: You can combine GDI+ (typographic) measuring both parts to find relative widths. Thenposition the Label accordingly..

Comment: @TaW, Yes, I was thinking about it when I mentioned GDI+, but I am not good with GDI+ and was wondering if there is an easier solution.

Comment: If you want arbitrary alignment like this, there is no easier solution than drawing it manually. That will, of course, require you to measure it as well. If it's a `Label` control, it's actually being drawn with GDI, not GDI+, and you should stick with that. `TextRenderer.DrawText` for the output, `TextRenderer.MeasureText` to, well, measure.

Comment: @CodyGray, thank you, it seems I will have to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a positioning function that should help:

```
void positionTo(Label lbl, Panel pan, int pos)
{
    SizeF sz0, sz1, sz2;
    sz0 = sz1 = sz2 = Size.Empty;
    using (Graphics g = lbl.CreateGraphics())
    {
        StringFormat sf = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;
        sz0 = g.MeasureString(lbl.Text, lbl.Font, pan.Width, sf);
        sz1 = g.MeasureString(lbl.Text.Substring(0, pos), lbl.Font, pan.Width, sf);
        sz2 = g.MeasureString(lbl.Text.Substring(pos), lbl.Font, pan.Width, sf);
    }
    lbl.Left = (int)(pan.Width / 2 - sz1.Width);
}
```

[image]

Note that I use only the left part measurement. One could use both to refine the centering..

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it.

Comment: @TaW can you give a link for this simple sample ?

Comment: What do you mean?? This is the `numericUpDown1_ValueChanged` event code:  `positionTo(label2, panel1, (int)numericUpDown1.Value);`

Comment: If you are letting the label draw its own text, this will give you the wrong results. Like all controls, labels draw their text using GDI rendering, for a variety of complicated reasons. In short, it's better, sharper, and faster than GDI+. `Graphics.MeasureString`/`DrawString` are both GDI+. What you want in order to match is `TextRenderer.MeasureText`/`DrawText`. And even if you're custom-drawing the text, too, you should be using `TextRenderer.DrawText`, because it's better, sharper, and faster. :-) This is a common point of confusion, so I just wanted to clarify my earlier comment.

Comment: I don't use owner-drawing in my example and would not suggest doing so. - As `TextRenderer.MeasureText` has no option like the `GenericTypographic` it always comes with way too large sizes, which ok when we want to concatenate string we draw, but not here. It may work when using left and right size and calculating a percentage to use along wit the actual Label.Width, the Label having AutoSize on..